# Output and input a 3D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, ifstream, ofstream

I am working on a c++ code and want to output my 3d array to a txt file. And then, input the content of this 3d file into another c++ code.

```
//Assume that I have a function named Function() that returns float numbers.
double array1[10][20][30];
ofstream out1("3Darray.txt");
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){
  for(int j=0; j< 20; j++){
    for(int k=0; k< 30; k++){
      out1 << Function() << " ";
    }
  }
}
//Now, input it into the array.
ifstream file("3Darray.txt");
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){
  for(int j=0; j< 20; j++){
    for(int k=0; k< 30; k++){
      file >> array1[i][j][k];
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you just need to make sure 'file' exists before you enter your loops:

if(file.is_open()){ /*proceed with loops*/}

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/  (scroll down to 'Open a File')

Comment: Close the file after writing. It's probably locking the file  so the reader can't open.

Comment: out1 << Function() << " ";

Comment: Is the structure correct? This method works for 1D and 2D arrays. Just not for 3D arrays.

Comment: any other method suggestions would be appreciated as well.

Comment: If I use vector, then there is memory leak